# Printer Cannon I-Sensys MF212W

Tags: drivers

I want to install printer Cannon I-Sensys MF212W on Ubuntu can anyone help me, please

Answer (score 1):

"Canon UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux" is a Linux operating system printer driver that supports Canon devices. It uses the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) printing system for Linux operating systems.

1. Download [UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V3.40](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf212w.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)). There are both 64-bit and 32-bit drivers included in the same .tar.gz archive. Start the download and immediately copy the download link to get the link for downloading the latest driver for the Canon i-SENSYS MF212w printer. I already completed Step 1. and typed the download link for you in Step 2.
2. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   wget -c http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0100002708/17/linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz  
   tar xvzf linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz  
   cd linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/  # for 32-bit OS replace `64-bit_Driver` with `32-bit_Driver`
   sudo apt install ./cndrvcups-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb      
   sudo apt install ./cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_3.40-1_amd64.deb    
   sudo apt install ./cndrvcups-utility_1.00-1_amd64.deb   
   sudo service cups restart
   ```
3. Add the Canon MF212w printer from *System Settings* -> *Printers* -> *Add* -> *Printer*.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a driver located at https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf212w.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit) for this printer.  It downloads in a 'tar.gz' file, and instructions about installing from such a file can be found at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)